# java.io.IOException: Container is not running while using GIT docker image

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, devops

I am trying to use alpine/git image in my jenkins pipeline but getting below error in system logs

```
Error in provisioning; template='DockerTemplate{configVersion=2, labelString='git', connector=io.jenkins.docker.connector.DockerComputerAttachConnector@783b8a96, remoteFs='/', instanceCap=2147483647, mode=EXCLUSIVE, retentionStrategy=com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.strategy.DockerOnceRetentionStrategy@b86010e, dockerTemplateBase=DockerTemplateBase{image='alpine/git', pullCredentialsId='', registry=null, dockerCommand='docker run -ti --rm -v ${HOME}:/root -v $(pwd):/git alpine/git version', hostname='', user='', extraGroups=[], dnsHosts=[], network='', volumes=[], volumesFrom2=[], environment=[], bindPorts='', bindAllPorts=false, memoryLimit=null, memorySwap=null, cpuShares=null, shmSize=null, privileged=false, securityOpts=null, tty=false, macAddress='null', extraHosts=[], extraDockerLabels=null}, removeVolumes=false, pullStrategy=PULL_NEVER, nodeProperties=[], disabled=BySystem,0 ms,4 min 59 sec,Template provisioning failed.}' for cloud='docker'
java.io.IOException: Container is not running.
    at io.jenkins.docker.connector.DockerComputerConnector.createLauncher(DockerComputerConnector.java:96)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerTemplate.doProvisionNode(DockerTemplate.java:574)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerTemplate.provisionNode(DockerTemplate.java:536)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerCloud$1.run(DockerCloud.java:370)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am using my Ubuntu system as docker slave to run git docker image and my Jenkins is on windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have set up your Ubuntu system as a Docker cloud in Jenkins and are now trying to use alpine:git image to create a slave?

If so, I'm afraid it's not possible. Only a specially prepared Docker images, with right dependencies installed can be used to create Jenkins slaves. See [here](https://devopscube.com/docker-containers-as-build-slaves-jenkins/) for details.

Of course, there is no reason you can't prepare your image using alpine:git as a base.

Comment: You're welcome. If you find my answer useful, please accept it.